# Handling nested records of lists in f#

Tags: list, f#, record, readability

I am currently having some trouble elegantly handling nested record lists.

lets say we have the types:

```
type BoxEntry = {
     flag : bool
}

type Box = {
     entries : BoxEntry list
}

type Entry = {
     boxes : Box list
}

type Model = {
    recEntries : Entry list
}
```

Now lets say I want to set a specific boxentry bool I have the list indexes of Entry, Box and BoxEntry however I have only found this approach to work for me:

```
let handleUnsetEntry (model : Model) (idxs : string* int * int) =
    let(sendId, bi, ej) = idxs

    let nEntry =
        model.entries
            |> List.map(fun x ->
                if x.sendId = sendId then
                   {x with boxes =
                            x.boxes |> List.mapi (fun i y ->
                                if i = bi then
                                    {y with boxEntry =
                                                y.boxEntry |> List.mapi (fun j z ->
                                                                if j = ej then
                                                                    z.SetFlag
                                                                else
                                                                    z)}
                                else
                                    y)}
                else
                    x)


    {model with entries = nEntry}, Cmd.none
```

This is obviously a really silly solution both efficiency-wise as well as readability-wise. Is there another approach to this which is more elegant I feel like there surely must be but I am not getting it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should ask yourself why you need to do this in the first place. Usually it's because your application model isn't designed to fit your application needs, but rather to fit whatever shape the data you get from the server has. If your model had fit your application, you would probably have nested update functions for each type that construct the new model level by level, rather than global functions that each does everything in isolation. This is an architecture question that is probably too broad to properly answer here. You might try a forum or [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: If you have the list indexes, you could just use `List.item` to fetch the item at that index. The docs haven't been updated yet to mention it, but `List.item 2` fetches the third item in the list (it's zero-based indexing). **BUT** do note that this is an O(N) operation, whereas looking up an index in an array is O(1). So like glennsl said, the real solution to your problem involves rethinking how you store your data. For starters, if you're constantly indexing into these lists, what if you stored them in arrays instead? There are probably even better solutions, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In FP there's a pattern called Lens or Prism. It's kind of composable functional attributes to simplify handling of nested immutable structures.

Lenses/Prisms allows you to zoom in on a nested attribute and get/set it while preserving immutability (set returns a new object).

Lenses/Prisms doesn't really answer what to do IIRC with structures that contains lists but if we ignore that and "hack something" we could end up with something like this:

```
type Prism<'O, 'I> = P of ('O -> 'I option)*('O -> 'I -> 'O)
```

That is, a prism consists of two functions; a getter and a setter. The getter given an outer value returns the inner value if it exists. The setter creates a new outer value given a new inner value.

This allows us too define the commonly used `fstL` and `sndL` prisms that allows zooming on the first respectively the second part of a pair.

```
let fstL = 
  let g o         = o |> fst |> Some
  let s (_, s) i  = (i, s)
  P (g, s)

let sndL = 
  let g o         = o |> snd |> Some
  let s (f, _) i  = (f, i)
  P (g, s)
```

We also define a way to combine two prisms

```
// Combines two prisms into one
let combineL (P (lg, ls)) (P (rg, rs)) =
  let g o   = 
    match lg o with 
    | None    -> None
    | Some io -> rg io
  let s o i = 
    match lg o with
    | None    -> o
    | Some io -> ls o (rs io i)
  P (g, s)
let (>->) l r = combine l r
```

Using this we can define a prism that allows zooming into a rather complex structure:

```
let l = sndL >-> sndL >-> fstL
let o = (1, (2, (3, 4)))
get l o |> printfn "%A"  //Prints 3
let o = set l o 33
get l o |> printfn "%A"  //Prints 33
```

Given the Model given by OP we extend it with Prisms static attributes

```
type BoxEntry = 
  {
    flag : bool
  }
  member x.SetFlag = {x with flag = true}

  // Prisms requires some boiler plate code, this could be generated
  static member flagL = 
    let g (o : BoxEntry)    = Some o.flag
    let s (o : BoxEntry) i  = { o with flag = i }
    P (g, s)
```

Putting it all together we can rewrite the handle function to something like this:

```
let handleUnsetEntry (model : Model) (idxs : string* int * int) =
  let (sendId, bi, ej) = idxs

  // Builds a Prism to the nested flag
  let nestedFlagL = 
    Model.entriesL 
    >-> Prism.listElementL   (fun _ (e : Entry) -> e.sendId) sendId
    >-> Entry.boxesL
    >-> Prism.listElementAtL bi
    >-> Box.boxEntryL
    >-> Prism.listElementAtL ej
    >-> BoxEntry.flagL

  Prism.set nestedFlagL model true
```

Hope this gave OP some ideas on how one can handle nested immutable structures.

The full source code:

```
// A Prism is a composable optionally available property
//  It consist of a getter function that given an outer object returns 
//    the inner object if it's there
//  Also a setter function that allows setting the inner object 
//    (if there's a feasible place)
//  In FP there are patterns called Lens and Prisms, this is kind of a bastard Prism
type Prism<'O, 'I> = P of ('O -> 'I option)*('O -> 'I -> 'O)

module Prism =
  let get (P (g, _)) o    = g o
  let set (P (_, s)) o i  = s o i

  let fstL = 
    let g o         = o |> fst |> Some
    let s (_, s) i  = (i, s)
    P (g, s)

  let sndL = 
    let g o         = o |> snd |> Some
    let s (f, _) i  = (f, i)
    P (g, s)

  // Combines two prisms into one
  let combineL (P (lg, ls)) (P (rg, rs)) =
    let g o   = 
      match lg o with 
      | None    -> None
      | Some io -> rg io
    let s o i = 
      match lg o with
      | None    -> o
      | Some io -> ls o (rs io i)
    P (g, s)

  // Creates a Prism for accessing a listElement
  let listElementL sel k =
    let g o   =
      o
      |> List.mapi    (fun i v -> (sel i v), v) 
      |> List.tryPick (fun (kk, vv) -> if k = kk then Some vv else None)
    let s o i = 
      o
      |> List.mapi    (fun i v -> (sel i v), v) 
      |> List.map     (fun (kk, vv) -> if k = kk then i else vv)
    P (g, s)

  let listElementAtL i =
    listElementL (fun j _ -> j) i

type Prism<'O, 'I> with
  static member (>->) (l, r) = Prism.combineL l r

// Modified model to match the code in OPs post

type BoxEntry = 
  {
    flag : bool
  }
  member x.SetFlag = {x with flag = true}

  // Prisms requires some boiler plate code, this could be generated
  static member flagL = 
    let g (o : BoxEntry)    = Some o.flag
    let s (o : BoxEntry) i  = { o with flag = i }
    P (g, s)

type Box = 
  {
    boxEntry : BoxEntry list
  }

  static member boxEntryL = 
    let g (o : Box)    = Some o.boxEntry
    let s (o : Box) i  = { o with boxEntry = i }
    P (g, s)

type Entry = 
  {
    sendId : string
    boxes : Box list
  }

  static member sendIdL = 
    let g (o : Entry)    = Some o.sendId
    let s (o : Entry) i  = { o with sendId = i }
    P (g, s)

  static member boxesL = 
    let g (o : Entry)    = Some o.boxes
    let s (o : Entry) i  = { o with boxes = i }
    P (g, s)

type Model = 
  {
    entries : Entry list
  }

  static member entriesL = 
    let g (o : Model)    = Some o.entries
    let s (o : Model) i  = { o with entries = i }
    P (g, s)

let handleUnsetEntry (model : Model) (idxs : string* int * int) =
  let (sendId, bi, ej) = idxs

  // Builds a Prism to the nested flag
  let nestedFlagL = 
    Model.entriesL 
    >-> Prism.listElementL   (fun _ (e : Entry) -> e.sendId) sendId
    >-> Entry.boxesL
    >-> Prism.listElementAtL bi
    >-> Box.boxEntryL
    >-> Prism.listElementAtL ej
    >-> BoxEntry.flagL

  Prism.set nestedFlagL model true

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let model : Model =
    {
      entries = 
        [
          {
            sendId  = "123"
            boxes   = 
              [
                {
                  boxEntry = 
                    [
                      {
                        flag = false
                      }
                      {
                        flag = false
                      }
                    ]
                }
              ]
          }
        ]
    }

  printfn "Before change"  
  printfn "%A" model

  let model = handleUnsetEntry model ("123", 0, 0)

  printfn "After 1st change"  
  printfn "%A" model

  let model = handleUnsetEntry model ("123", 0, 1)

  printfn "After 2nd change"  
  printfn "%A" model

  let model = handleUnsetEntry model ("Hello?", 0, 1)

  printfn "After missed change"  
  printfn "%A" model

  0
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the amount of effort in this post, will definitively look into this.